# How to add text to header in nsis?

Tags: installation, nsis

I want to add header title in my welcome page page of my nsis installer like the image i had attached.
I have already tried this below line but it is adding some line to title instead of header

```
MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE '${WELCOME_TITLE}'
```

So is there any way to achieve this.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a normal Modern UI page you would do:

```
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT foo
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT bar
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
```

It looks like you are not using the MUI that ships with NSIS but some 3rd party add-on, check their documentation if the code above does not work...